# Обычно(,) если всё хорошо, я еду по грибам-ягодам

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Обычно(,) если всё хорошо, я еду по грибам-ягодам.

> Обычно(,) если всё хорошо, то я еду по грибам-ягодам.

Comment: Обычно, если всё хорошо - я еду по грибам-ягодам. А не обычно, когда плохо всё, то - катаюсь.

Comment: По грибы, однако. По ягоды или за ягодами. По грибам ездить — новая забава?

Comment: А по делам можно ездить?

Comment: По делам можно. Я еду, у меня там дело - по делу. А я еду у меня там гриб - звучит странно: еду по грибу, еду, еду, переехал - раздавил гриб.

Comment: @буратино Сэр, но ведь  грамматическая форма одинаковая: ездить по делам, ездить по грибам. Как вы это объясните? Честно говоря, мне очень нравится это выражение – ездить по грибам.  Вы только представьте себе картинку: классно, художественно! А что вам не нравится? Грамматическая модель одна и та же, да и к Т.п. нет вопросов. Вы же режете колбасу ножом и колечками, и ничего))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) ***Обычно, если** всё хорошо, я еду по грибы-ягоды.*

(2) ***Обычно если** всё хорошо, то я еду по грибы-ягоды.*

Думаю, что во втором предложении наречие **можно отнести к придаточному** по образцу п.5 в правилах  [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) (слова: ***особенно, в частности***).

Ответ **справочной службы** русского языка.

Предлог **по** в значении "за" (**по воду, по грибы, по ягоды**) имеет очень ограниченную сферу употребления и является **разговорным.**

**Примеры из [Нацкорпуса:](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnUiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIgogCh4KA3JlcRIXChXQvtCx0YvRh9C90L4g0LXRgdC70LgwAA==)**

***Обычно если** задерживался, то там и оставался ночевать.*

***Обычно если** вечером или ночью происходило ограбление, то утром следующего дня деньги перечислялись на счет того или иного учреждения.*

— Знаете, господа, по-моему, самое сильное впечатление — это когда ищешь что-то, долго-долго, может, всю жизнь, и уже почти смиришься, что не нашел и никогда не найдешь — и вдруг вот оно...

Comment: Так это же наречие, а не частица. Наречие должно относиться к главному, оно не усиливает придаточное. Попробуйте переставить: _Если всë обычно хорошо, то я еду по грибам-ягодам_. Согласитесь, не подходит же.

Comment: Максим, мне нравится ваша увлеченность языком, но вы не хотите мыслить свободно. Откуда у вас в голове столько долгов и запретов?) Старайтесь меньше использовать такие слова, как  «должно».  Наречие нам ничего не должно, он может использоваться в значении частицы, что мы и видим в худ. текстах. То есть модифицировать условное значение союза ЕСЛИ. Можно или нельзя переставить? Это технический прием, не более того. Не надо его возводить в абсолют.

Comment: И еще хорошо бы вам разобраться с темой о различной позиции придаточного в предложении  (3 варианта). Интерпозиция не всегда хороша: там вставочная интонация и добавочное значение.

Comment: Кстати, что такое Нацкорпус? Ему можно на 100 % доверять в плане русского языка?

Comment: Никому не доверяйте на 100 %))  Это собрание различных текстов для работы с ними, очень полезный ресурс. Выбирайте авторитетных авторов, учитывайте время и т.д. – и принимайте решение.

Answer (score 0):

В первом примере запятая ставится:

***Обычно, если всё хорошо, я еду по грибам-ягодам***.

Слово *обычно* является обычным членом предложения, это слово не является союзом, чтобы его не отделять от другого союза. А в данном примере это слово обязательно нужно отделить от придаточной части, оно может быть **только в главной**.

---

Второй вариант тоже корректен:

***Обычно, если всё хорошо, то я еду по грибам-ягодам***.

Слово *обычно* также нужно отделить от придаточной части. Слово *обычно* можно переставить:

***Если всё хорошо, то обычно я еду по грибам-ягодам***.

Хотя у самого придаточного **фиксированная позиция**, поэтому его никак не переставишь, только слово *обычно* можно.

Comment: Но нельзя во втором случае переставить, а в первой — можно!  *1. Обычно я еду по грибам-ягодам, если всё хорошо; 2. Обычно **то** я еду по грибам-ягодам, если всё хорошо.*

Comment: Во втором примере довольно-таки сложно разобраться в структуре предложения. Слово _обычно_ и во втором относится к главному, но после _то_, а не перед. Хотя... Блин, сложно очень разобраться...